# Unable to pass Checkbox values to a database

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am building a simple form with text fields as well as an image upload and checkbox options.

I need people to be able to select multiple checkboxes, and those need to be passed to a database.

All the form fields are passing to the database with no issue, except for the Videos(checkbox) field.

Because of the nature of the form, I am required to use client side javascript to pass the form fields via json to SSJS.

At this point, the checkbox values do post to the console log, but they do not make their way to the database. Any help will be much appreciated.

```js
 var btn = document.getElementById("button");
      btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
          var files = document.getElementById("file").files;
          if (files.length > 0) {
              getBase64(files[0]);
          }
});
  
function getChcked() {
    var form = document.getElementById('myform');
    var chks = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    var checked = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++){
        if(chks[i].checked){
            checked.push(chks[i].value)
        }
    }
    return checked;
};
          var Videos = '';
  
  function getBase64(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = function() {

          //prepare data to pass to processing page 
          var fileEncoded = reader.result;
          var base64enc = fileEncoded.split(";base64,")[1];
          var fullFileName = document.getElementById("file").files[0].name;
          var fileName = fullFileName.split(".")[0];
          var assetName = fullFileName.split(".")[1];
          var AgencyName = document.getElementById("AgencyName").value;
          var AgencyPhone = document.getElementById("AgencyPhone").value;
          var AgencyEmail = document.getElementById("AgencyEmail").value;
          var AgencyWebsite = document.getElementById("AgencyWebsite").value;
          var Videos = console.log(getChcked());

        
                                   
          fetch("processingpage", {  //provide URL of the processing page
                  method: "POST",
                  headers: {
                      "Content-Type": "application/json"
                  },
                  body: JSON.stringify({
                      base64enc: base64enc,
                      fileName: fileName,
                      assetName: assetName,
                      AgencyName: AgencyName,
                      AgencyPhone: AgencyPhone,
                      AgencyEmail: AgencyEmail,
                      AgencyWebsite: AgencyWebsite,
                      Videos: Videos
                  })
              });
              
      };
      
  }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Videos">Select which video(s) you’d like co-branded:</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="Videos-0">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Videos" id="Videos-0" value="The Flour Child">
      The Flour Child
    </label>
 </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="Videos-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Videos" id="Videos-1" value="The Loose Tooth Situation">
      The Loose Tooth Situation
    </label>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

console.log returns undefined, so you are assigning undefined to Videos

```
var Videos = console.log(getChcked()); // equivalent to var Videos=undefined;
```